# External Library Uncatchable exception

Tags: java, exception

I call a function from an external library called runFile which allows me running external scripts from file. I succesfully call any script I want to run with that function, but the problem is that I don't know how to detect when the script I run is aborted by the user in a dialog.

The description of the function in the library is the following:

*String runFile (String sScriptPath)*

*Description: Run script from file(s)*

*Parameters: sScriptPath file name which is either full path, wildcard mask or just base name, in this case the file issearched in current directory or using ucam.db key.*

*Returns: String RUN_STATUS_OK if run is OK, otherwise returns message about issue encountered.
Exceptions: AbortException if any problem encountered during script call*

And my code is the following:

```
try{
    //Protected code
    RunFileReturn = runFile("C:\\macros\\ucammacros\\Blocs.vhs",[{HabemusRear,bRepetError}]);       
    if(!isEqual(RunFileReturn,"OK"))
    {
        promptStart();  
            promptLabel("");
            promptLabel("Hi ha hagut un error al repassar els pads als blocs.");
            promptLabel("");
            promptLabel("Aborta i recupera el circuit des de l'últim checkpoint.");
        promptEnd();
    }
}catch(AbortException e)
{
    //Catch block
    promptStart();  
        promptLabel("Exception found.");
    promptEnd();
    //do something more

}
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong? RunFileReturn always returns "OK" except when there's no such a file and I never get to the catch block.

Help please! Thanks!

Comment: Replace `AbortException` with `Throwable`.

Comment: I just tried, didn't worked...

Comment: That means there is no exception from external library in your case.

Comment: Possibly bad documentation - maybe certain types of problems return a message and *don't* throw exceptions. Have you tried printing out what it returns when it doesn't return "OK"?

Comment: Oops.. then that means the AbortException described above is caused by other errors different that user cancellation, isn't it?

Comment: immibis, I tried, but it always returns "OK" unless the file I want to run with runFile doesn't exists.